# How to keep IDs unique for Ajax-programming?

Tags: javascript, ajax

It seems to me that most things in Ajax-programming are solved by "inventing" IDs. The problem that might occur is, to keep the IDs unique. How do you solve the problem (for example when managing a list of messages, …)? By generating long randomized strings?

Comment: What exactly do you need ids for? "*thing in ajax-programming*" is a very vague term

Answer (score 1):

If these messages correspond to something server-side in a database, you should use the ID from the database (if they don't have a unique identifier in the database, they should).

If they exist solely on the client, you can use numerical IDs and increment each time.

Comment: I generally would try to avoid publishing anything that is related to the database structure. Also, one could either use classes and/or use common unique ancestors from which one can traverse the children. This avoids ID-flooding.